# Find Relevant MVC Template

Tags: c#, .net, templates, asp.net-mvc-2

My main View is calling Template view is as below:

```
  <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.AuthorizedCreditCard)%>
```

My Templates are as below :

[image]

Both above templates are consuming same model (i.e. `model.AuthorizedCreditCard`).

So My question is How to find which Template is runing when I call `EditorFor`.

I would like to have a **technical explanation**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the `EditorFor` helper uses the template whose name matches the name of the type being edited. So, if your `AuthorizedCreditCard` is an instance of something called `AuthorizedCreditCard`, then it should use `AuthorizedCreditCard.ascx`. If you want to use something else, you can pass the name of the template you want as a string, thus:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.AuthorizedCreditCard, "AuthorizedCreditCardEditer")%>
```

Comment: You may also override the default Editor Template by using the [UIHint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.uihint.aspx) Attribute `[UIHint("AuthorizedCreditCardEditer")]` on your model's `AuthorizedCreditCard` property.